# Updating array of structures in a function and passing it as parameter to other functions

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

I am learning to program with C and still struggle when it comes to some things, specially with pointers.

I am asked to make a program that will simulate a library manager. It will have the functions to add a book and the option to check info for a specific book (checking isbn to find that specific book).

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MENU_MESSAGE "\n1 Add book\n2 Check book info\n3 Exit"
int books_added = 0; //counts books added to the library (mainly for usage as index)

struct Bookinfo
{
    char nIsbn[10];
    char szTitle[60];
    char szType[15];
    char szPublisher[25];
    int nPages;
    float nPrice;
    int nYear;
    int nStatus;
    char szName[40];
};
struct Bookinfo Library_manager[100]; // up to 100 books

//---------------------------------------------------------------

void menu(struct Bookinfo Library_manager[])
{
    int nUser; // user's choice for the menu
    printf(MENU_MESSAGE);
    printf("\n\nSelect a number from the menu: ");
    scanf("%d", &nUser);
    menu_direct(nUser, Library_manager);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------

int check_ISBN(char *szUser_isbn, int *nUser,struct Bookinfo Library_manager[])
{
    int i; // counter

    if(books_added==0) // no need to check for first book
        return 0;
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<=(books_added-1);i++) //iterates over library to check isbn
        {
            printf("\n\nentered ISBN: %s", szUser_isbn); //for testing
            printf("\nISBN of book in library: \n%s", Library_manager[i].nIsbn); //for testing
            if(szUser_isbn==Library_manager[i].nIsbn)// already in library
            {
                if(*nUser==2)
                    return i; // returns index of book with given isbn
                else
                    return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0; //not found in library
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------

void add_book(char *szUser_isbn, struct Bookinfo Library_manager[])
{
    strcpy(Library_manager[books_added].nIsbn, szUser_isbn);
    printf("\nEnter the book's title: ");
    scanf("%s", &Library_manager[books_added].szTitle);
    getchar(); // takes \n character
    printf("\nEnter the book's type: ");
    scanf("%s", &Library_manager[books_added].szType);
    getchar(); // takes \n character
    printf("\nEnter the book's publisher: ");
    scanf("%s", &Library_manager[books_added].szPublisher);
    getchar(); // takes \n character
    printf("\nEnter the book's number of pages: ");
    scanf("%d", &Library_manager[books_added].nPages);
    getchar(); // takes \n character
    printf("\nEnter the book's price: ");
    scanf("%f", &Library_manager[books_added].nPrice);
    getchar(); // takes \n character
    printf("\nEnter the book's year of publication: ");
    scanf("%d", &Library_manager[books_added].nYear);
    getchar(); // takes \n character
    Library_manager[books_added].nStatus=0; // book is available
    strcpy(Library_manager[books_added].szName, "None"); // not owned by anyone

    printf("\nISBN of book in library: %s", Library_manager[books_added].nIsbn); //for testing

    books_added+=1;
    printf("\nBook added succesfully to the library.\n\n");
    menu(Library_manager);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------

void display_book_details(int nUser)
{
    char szUser_isbn[10]; // book's isbn
    int nCheck_result; // 0 if book not in library, or index at wich it was found

    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter a valid ISBN: ");
        scanf("%s", szUser_isbn); // get book's isbn for checking
        getchar(); // gets \n character
        nCheck_result=check_ISBN(szUser_isbn,nUser, Library_manager);

        if (nCheck_result==0)
        {
            printf("\nThe ISBN was not found.");
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n-----------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("Book's Title: %s\t", Library_manager[nCheck_result].szTitle);
            printf("\nBook's ISBN: %s", szUser_isbn);
            printf("\nBook's Type: %s", Library_manager[nCheck_result].szType);
            printf("\nBook's Publisher: %s", Library_manager[nCheck_result].szPublisher);
            printf("\nBook's number of pages: %d", Library_manager[nCheck_result].nPages);
            printf("\nBook's Price: %f", Library_manager[nCheck_result].nPrice);
            printf("\nBook's publication year: %d", Library_manager[nCheck_result].nYear);

            if(Library_manager[nCheck_result].nStatus==0)
            {
                printf("\nBook's Status: Available");
            }
            else if (Library_manager[nCheck_result].nStatus==1)
            {
                printf("\nBook's Status: Checked-out");
            }

            printf("\nBook's current holder: %s", Library_manager[nCheck_result].szName);
        }
    }while(nCheck_result==0);

    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\nPress any key to continue to menu...");
    getch();
    menu(Library_manager);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------

int menu_direct(int nUser,struct Bookinfo Library_manager[]) // directs user's input
{
    if(nUser==1)
    {
        char szUser_isbn[10]; // new book's isbn
        int nCheck_result; // 0 if book not in library, 1 if found in library

        printf("Enter the book's ISBN: ");

        do
        {
            scanf("%s", szUser_isbn); // get book's isbn for checking
            getchar(); // takes \n character
            nCheck_result=check_ISBN(szUser_isbn,nUser, Library_manager);

            if (nCheck_result==0)
                add_book(szUser_isbn, &nUser);
            else
                printf("\nThe ISBN entered is already in library. Enter another ISBN: ");
        }while(nCheck_result==1);
    }
    else if (nUser==2)
    {
        if(books_added==0)
        {
            printf("\nThere are no books in the library yet\n");
            menu(Library_manager);
        }
        else
            display_book_details(nUser);
    }
    else if (nUser==3)
        return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------

int main(void)
{
    printf("-------------- Welcome --------------\n");
    menu(Library_manager);
    printf("Bye...");

    return 0;
}
```

If I run it, it does compile without showing any error but when I get to the part of checking info for a book (after I entered at least 1 book) I can't get the ISBN from the book that I previously added from the array so that I can compare it with this code `if(szUser_isbn==Library_manager[i].nIsbn)`.

I think it has something to do with pointers. I already looked at a vast amount of examples but none of them fitted my situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many many warnings you need to take care of. Always compile with **warnings** enabled. Minimum `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o outfile progname.c` You will see what I mean. I think you will find your issues quickly then.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks, for the info. I have this warning but I don't know how to solve it: `|63| warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[60]' [-Wformat]|`, do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I can't up-vote homework questions.

Comment: @Alex - I fixed that for you below in my answer. You just had the arguments to the function messed up (It just looked like a brain-fart, (wrong arguments) not a lack of understanding). I think you had `nuser` where you should have had `Library_manager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compiled with `-Wall -Wextra` then you have found `99%` of the problems. There were additional logic errors, such as comparison of `strings` requires `strcmp` (or the like) and `==` will not work. The return for `check_ISBN` failed for the first book every time because array indexes are `zero` based in C (i.e. `0 - n-1`, not `1 - n`).

I have also changed your `format string` in each of your `scanf` statements to automatically consume the trailing `newline`. (e.g. `scanf("%d%*c", &nUser);`) This prevents needing `getchar()` but is a temporary fix, because entering `nothing` will pass the `newline` to the next input. You may want to make this more robust.

I have left the logic errors in your code (commented out) and made additional suggestions to tidy up the code. They are contained below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MENU_MESSAGE "\n1 Add book\n2 Check book info\n3 Exit"

int books_added = 0; //counts books added to the library (mainly for usage as index)

struct Bookinfo
{
    char nIsbn[10];
    char szTitle[60];
    char szType[15];
    char szPublisher[25];
    int nPages;
    float nPrice;
    int nYear;
    int nStatus;
    char szName[40];
};
struct Bookinfo Library_manager[100]; // up to 100 books

//---------------------------------------------------------------

int menu_direct(int nUser,struct Bookinfo Library_manager[]);

//---------------------------------------------------------------

void menu(struct Bookinfo Library_manager[])
{
    int nUser; // user's choice for the menu
    printf(MENU_MESSAGE);
    printf("\n\nSelect a number from the menu: ");
    scanf("%d%*c", &nUser);
    menu_direct(nUser, Library_manager);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------

int check_ISBN(char *szUser_isbn, int *nUser,struct Bookinfo Library_manager[])
{
    int i; // counter

    if(books_added==0) // no need to check for first book
        return 0;
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<=(books_added-1);i++) //iterates over library to check isbn
        {
            printf("\n\nentered ISBN: '%s'", szUser_isbn); //for testing
            printf("\nISBN of book in library: \n%s", Library_manager[i].nIsbn); //for testing
            // if(szUser_isbn==Library_manager[i].nIsbn)// already in library
            if ( strcmp (szUser_isbn, Library_manager[i].nIsbn) == 0)// already in library
            {
                if(*nUser==2)
                    return i; // returns index of book with given isbn
                else
                    return 1;
            }
        }
        // return 0; //not found in library
        return -1; //not found in library (0 is first index)
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------

void add_book(char *szUser_isbn, struct Bookinfo Library_manager[])
{
    strcpy(Library_manager[books_added].nIsbn, szUser_isbn);
    printf("  Enter the book's title    : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", Library_manager[books_added].szTitle);
    // getchar(); // takes \n character
    printf("  Enter the book's type     : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", Library_manager[books_added].szType);
    // getchar(); // takes \n character
    printf("  Enter the book's publisher: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", Library_manager[books_added].szPublisher);
    // getchar(); // takes \n character
    printf("  Enter the number of pages : ");
    scanf("%d%*c", &Library_manager[books_added].nPages);
    // getchar(); // takes \n character
    printf("  Enter the book's price    : ");
    scanf("%f%*c", &Library_manager[books_added].nPrice);
    // getchar(); // takes \n character
    printf("  Enter year of publication : ");
    scanf("%d%*c", &Library_manager[books_added].nYear);
    // getchar(); // takes \n character
    Library_manager[books_added].nStatus=0; // book is available
    strcpy(Library_manager[books_added].szName, "None"); // not owned by anyone

    printf("\nISBN of book in library: %s", Library_manager[books_added].nIsbn); //for testing

    books_added+=1;
    printf("\nBook added succesfully to the library.\n\n");
    menu(Library_manager);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------

void display_book_details(int nUser)
{
    char szUser_isbn[10]; // book's isbn
    int nCheck_result; // 0 if book not in library, or index at wich it was found

    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter a valid ISBN (-1 to exit): ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", szUser_isbn); // get book's isbn for checking
        //getchar(); // gets \n character
        nCheck_result=check_ISBN (szUser_isbn, &nUser, Library_manager);

        if (nCheck_result==-1)
        {
            printf("\nThe ISBN was not found.");
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n-----------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("  Book's Title           : %s\n", Library_manager[nCheck_result].szTitle);
            printf("  Book's ISBN            : %s\n", szUser_isbn);
            printf("  Book's Type            : %s\n", Library_manager[nCheck_result].szType);
            printf("  Book's Publisher       : %s\n", Library_manager[nCheck_result].szPublisher);
            printf("  Book's number of pages : %d\n", Library_manager[nCheck_result].nPages);
            printf("  Book's Price           : $%.2f\n", Library_manager[nCheck_result].nPrice);
            printf("  Book's publication year: %d\n", Library_manager[nCheck_result].nYear);

            if(Library_manager[nCheck_result].nStatus==0)
            {
                printf("\nBook's Status: Available");
            }
            else if (Library_manager[nCheck_result].nStatus==1)
            {
                printf("\nBook's Status: Checked-out");
            }

            printf("\nBook's current holder: %s", Library_manager[nCheck_result].szName);
        }
    } while (nCheck_result != -1);

    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\nPress any key to continue to menu...");
//     getch();
    menu(Library_manager);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------

int menu_direct(int nUser,struct Bookinfo Library_manager[]) // directs user's input
{
    if(nUser==1)
    {
        char szUser_isbn[10]; // new book's isbn
        int nCheck_result; // 0 if book not in library, 1 if found in library

        printf("\n  Enter the book's ISBN     : ");

        do
        {
            scanf("%[^\n]%*c", szUser_isbn); // get book's isbn for checking
            // getchar(); // takes \n character
            nCheck_result=check_ISBN(szUser_isbn, &nUser, Library_manager);

            if (nCheck_result==0)
                add_book(szUser_isbn, Library_manager);
            else
                printf("\nThe ISBN entered is already in library. Enter another ISBN: ");
        } while(nCheck_result==1);
    }
    else if (nUser==2)
    {
        if(books_added==0)
        {
            printf("\nThere are no books in the library yet\n");
            menu(Library_manager);
        }
        else
            display_book_details(nUser);
    }
    else if (nUser==3)
        return 0;

    return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------

int main(void)
{
    printf("-------------- Welcome --------------\n");
    menu(Library_manager);
    printf("Bye...\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/bookmgr
-------------- Welcome --------------

1 Add book
2 Check book info
3 Exit

Select a number from the menu: 1

  Enter the book's ISBN     : 123
  Enter the book's title    : Huck Finn
  Enter the book's type     : fiction
  Enter the book's publisher: Random House
  Enter the number of pages : 432
  Enter the book's price    : $19.99
  Enter year of publication : 2001

ISBN of book in library: 123
Book added succesfully to the library.


1 Add book
2 Check book info
3 Exit

Select a number from the menu: 2

Enter a valid ISBN (-1 to exit): 123


entered ISBN: '123'
ISBN of book in library:
123
-----------------------------------------------
  Book's Title           : Huck Finn
  Book's ISBN            : 123
  Book's Type            : fiction
  Book's Publisher       : Random House
  Book's number of pages : 432
  Book's Price           : 19.990000.2
  Book's publication year: 2001

Book's Status: Available
Book's current holder: None
Enter a valid ISBN (-1 to exit): -1


entered ISBN: '-1'
ISBN of book in library:
123
The ISBN was not found.
-----------------------------------------------

Press any key to continue to menu...
1 Add book
2 Check book info
3 Exit

Select a number from the menu: 3
Bye...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am happy to say that I had managed to fix most of the errors thanks to the warnings, but still needed the explanation. I was also missing the -1 and had some errors in my syntax when calling functions. Thanks for taking the time

Comment: You bet. The key to learning C is to -- **slow down**. C is an **exact** language, that is one if its strengths, but it is frustrating while learning because **"there is no close-enough"**. However, to give you the low-level hardware control that C does, that is required. Taking a little more time with C, is time well spent.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `check_ISBN()` doesn't distinguish between a book found at index 0 and one not found. Also you are not comparing the ISBNs but their pointers. The initial test of `books_added` is unnecessary - the `for` loop does that for you. I suggest the function returns `-1` if the book is not found, then the caller can check the function result as `>= 0`

```
int check_ISBN(char *szUser_isbn, int *nUser,struct Bookinfo Library_manager[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<books_added; i++) //iterates over library to check isbn
        if(strcmp (szUser_isbn, Library_manager[i].nIsbn) == 0) // already in library
            return i; // returns index of book with given isbn
    return -1; //not found in library
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. When you say that I am not comparing the ISBN's, but their pointers, is that solved by using `strcmp (szUser_isbn, Library_manager[i].nIsbn)` ? and also I can't get the ISBN for the book already in the library to be displayed in my check_ISBN fucntion. I tried with `printf("\nISBN of book in library: \n%s", Library_manager[i].nIsbn);` but it just shows an empty space after the colon.